# Accessing to config values

Tags: php, laravel-5, environment-variables

I am trying to access to config values, in order to pass a token to a constructor and be able to add it to the headers. So basically what I did was in the TestCase class, in the constructor

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

   $this->token = Config::get('app.token');

}
```

Here I am getting:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set

Also, I tried with:

```php
$this->token = config('app.token');
```

And here

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist.

My other question would be, in case I can get the token, how do I can pass it to the header.

Thank you, and I hope you can understand what I tried to explain.

Comment: ```php artisan config:cache,
 php artisan config:clear,
 php artisan cache:clear,
 composer update
```
try following command and give it a try

Comment: Yes I tried. Still not working, same errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `app` container of the [TestCase class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php#L29);

The application container is available after `setUp` lifecycle method of the `TestCase` and not during it's construction.

```php
function setUp(): void 
{
    parent::setUp();

    $config = $this->app['config'];
    $this->token = $config->get('app.token');
}
```

Comment: Well, at least I got a different error. Now I am getting "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null"

Comment: What `TestCase` class are you subclassing for your tests? You may want to check there

Comment: Well, I am extending BaseTestCase, but I didn't find anything.  This is the class  abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication; }

Comment: $app is only set after `setUp` phase of the `TestCase` lifecycle and not in the constructor. I suggest to override `setUp` and retrieve `app.token` there

Comment: Worked! So at the end, it was a lifecycle issue.Thank you.